# Capturing a change in value of a column in consecutive rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I currently have the following dataframe

[image]

and need to create a new binary data frame which applies the following logic:

-If value in any column is >=1.5 and the preceeding value is <1.5, then show 1.

-Continue to show 1 unless the value drops <=0, then put 0.

So applying this to the above should yield:

[image]

Any idea how to do this most efficiently?

Comment: Data as a text please. We cant copy images

Comment: Thanks for showing your expected output, but no thanks, for showing them as text...

Comment: Your requirement statements says one thing and the output says the other wise .

Comment: Why do you say that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the approach I think should work.
First create new columns for each of the existing columns which will contain the existing column shifted upwards by one column.
ie if A is 0 1 1.5 
create A1 to 1 1.5 nan
U can use pandas shift to do that.
do it for all columns
Then,
if df is the name of your dataFrame

```
not_found_zero=1
for row in df.iterrows():
   if(not_found_zero):
        if row['A']<=0:
           row['A']=0
           flag=0
         else:
            row['A'] =(row['A']>=1.5) & (row['A1']>=1.5))   
    else:
       row['A']=0
```

Do this for all columns,and remember after u shift ,last column of A1 will be nan.
Delete the temperory rows after completion.